# mozroots command not found but man has it

Tags: macos, mono, frontend, fiddler, macos-sierra

I am new here to ask my first question.
I wanted to run fiddler2 on my Mac and I have downloaded the install package from the official website, which contains ".exe" files in it. And the installation guide tells me that I should install Mono Framework first.So I follow the guide and installed the Mono.But when I type in

```
mozroots --import --sync
```

in the terminal.It told me "command:mozroots not found".

Then I type

```
man mozroots
```

it showed me the description of mozroots. It looks like command mozroots exists in my Mac.
I searched many sites but there is no answer for it.

Could anyone tell me how to figure out this?
My mac is rmbp 2016 , macOS 10.12.4

Comment: `mozroots` is deprecated, use `cert-sync` instead.

Comment: Thanks but I just used `cert-sync` and the result is same. command not found.

Comment: You might be missing a path in your env, Check your mono install and within the `Commands` subdir you should find the scripts/binaries that you are looking for.

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Answer (score 0):

After installing Mono, try to open new terminal session. $PATH probably is not updated.

```
$ which mozroots
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mozroots

$ echo $PATH 
.../Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands ...
```